# C++ How to print a string backwards?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to print an `std::string` backwards with iterators like this:

```
std::string back = "hello";
for(std::string::iterator it=back.end(); it!=back.begin(); --it)
{
    std::cout << (*it);
}
```

But the output will only print out:

```
olle
```

Why is it not also printing out the h? I tried a couple of different things and played around with it, but I just can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!! :)

Comment: The problem is that `back.end()` points *behind* the string, and not at the last element. Have you tried http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator?

Comment: Why not use `std::reverse()`?

Comment: `it >= back.begin()`

Comment: the reason it fails is because begin points to the 'H' and you terminate the loop on that condition. Whereas end points to the char 'after' the 'o', and so o gets printed if you loop from  begin to end

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
std::string back = "hello";
for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = back.rbegin(); it != back.rend(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << (*it);
}
```

Comment: I will be using reverse iterators now that I know they exist. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
std::string::iterator it=back.end();
```

`it` gets initialized to `end()`. Then, inside of the loop:

```
std::cout << (*it);
```

Since the initial value of `it` is `end()`, dereferencing it is undefined behavior, with unpredictable results.

The correct approach is to decrement `it` ***before*** it gets dereferenced:

```
for(std::string::iterator it=back.end(); it!=back.begin(); )
{
    --it;
    std::cout << (*it);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. However, I was also going to suggest reverse iterators.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Thanks for the explanation for where I went wrong. I believe I will use reverse iterators for this though now that I know they exist :)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a for-loop:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string string_back = "hello";
std::reverse(string_back.begin(), string_back.end());
std::cout << string_back; // prints 'olleh'
```

Comment: In my case, I specifically want an iterator because I'm doing some transformation on each `char`, but I'll keep this in mind :)

Comment: Ah, I understand. Consider my answer knowledge for you in future cases.